# Changing Axis title in dimple.js by selecting through database

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have a database and created Bar chart x and y axes by calling it by creating X and Y variances as a droppable event.

Know I need to know about changing X and Y axis title by selecting it from the database.

My coding is just as:

```
var cparam = JSON.parse($('#' + $this.id).find('input.cparam').val());
                var X = '<span class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-left" style="margin-top: 2px;">X→</span><span  onclick="switchcolor(this);" class="draggable btn btn-xs btn-default" onmouseover="showtimes(this);"><span class="tag">' + cparam.X + '</span><span onclick="removetimes(this);" class="hide pull-right times">&times;</span><span class="agg hide">' + cparam.XAgg + '</span></span>';
                var Y = '<span class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-left" style="margin-top: 2px;">Y&nbsp; ↑</span><span onclick="switchcolor(this);" class="draggable btn btn-xs btn-default" onmouseover="showtimes(this);"><span class="tag">' + cparam.Y + '</span><span onclick="removetimes(this);" class="hide pull-right times">&times;</span><span class="agg hide">' + cparam.YAgg + '</span></span>';
```

And its value is called using:

```
 var c = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
            c.setBounds(60, 30, width - 80, height - 150)
            var x = c.addCategoryAxis("x", "x");
            c.addMeasureAxis("y", "Y");
            var mySeries = c.addSeries("x", dimple.plot.bar);
            //c.addLegend(60, 10, 500, 20, "right");
            //c.addLegend(320, 10, 90, 300, "left");
            mySeries.addEventHandler("dblclick", function (e) {
                debugger;
                var str = '';
                str = $("#" + currentChart).find('input.cvcols').val();
                var x = e.xValue;
                var y = e.yValue;
                if (str != '')
                    ShowTableViewCols(x, y, str);
            });
            c.draw();
```

If I have given this values I can only get the axis as x and y and not the value in it such as:

[IMG][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbCn.png

Is there any way to show the original X and Y axis value by using dimple.js or d3.js.

Comment: Your question is not clear... What exactly do you want to show?

Comment: In the given image I have to show the axis value from database instead of X and Y.. Is there any possibility??

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. The data shown in the chart will be the data given in the ```new dimple.chart(svg,data)``` call

Comment: If by "from database" you mean that you need to make an XHR call, then you should use d3.xhr methods: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Requests.md

Comment: Its just 'x.title' and 'y.title'. I have to show the title axis that is given as it in the database..

Comment: OK. stop using the database as an explanation. There is no database scheme in your question. There is only the data object there you are passing to the dimple.chart function. Do you want to rename the column names to some other values that are not in your data??

Comment: I have created a separate data in SQL and thereby I have called the values using the above coding as X and Y. Know I just need to know that is there any possibility for changing title of the axis which I have given as it is in my SQL. Its just showing X and Y as shown in the diagram which I was given in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the axes after drawing by saving the axis created and changing its title property:

```
var x = c.addCategoryAxis("x", "x");
x.title = X;
```

As in John's answer to my question: [Prevent dimple from renaming columns on redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373062/prevent-dimple-from-renaming-columns-on-redraw)